# WSo2 ESB saving records in database

Tags: java, wso2-esb

I want to make simple wso2 web service in XML that save records in database and print logs.

Answer (score 1):

To save the record in the database you can use the "[DB Report Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/DB+Report+Mediator)"

```
<dbreport xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name</url>
            <user>xxxx</user>
            <password>xxxx</password>
        </pool>
    </connection>
    <statement>
        <sql><![CDATA[insert into table_name (column1, column2, column3) values ( ?,?,? )]]></sql>
        <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="column1_entry"/>
        <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="column2_entry"/>
        <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="column3_entry"/>

    </statement>
</dbreport>
```

To get a record from a database, you can use the [DBLookup Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/DBLookup+Mediator)

```
  <dblookup>
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name</url>
            <user>xxxx</user>
            <password>xxxx</password>
        </pool>
    </connection>
    <statement>
        <sql><![CDATA[select * from table_name where column1 =  ?]]></sql>
        <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="column1_value"/>
        <result column="column1_name" name="result1"/>
        <result column="column2_name" name="result2"/>
        <result column="column3_name" name="result3"/>
    </statement>
  </dblookup>
```

We can log the results from the above dblookup statement using the [Log Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Log+Mediator)

```
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="get-property('result1')" name="log1"/>
    <property expression="get-property('result2')" name="log2"/>
    <property expression="get-property('result3')" name="log3"/>
</log>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DB Report Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/DB+Report+Mediator) for writing data and also use the log mediator for printing logs. For exposing the service you can create either a [proxy service](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Working+with+Proxy+Services) or a [rest api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Working+with+APIs)

Comment: i am using this code    
<sequence>
        <dbreport>
          <connection>
           <pool>
             <password>db-password</password>
             <user>db-username</user>
             <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
             <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
           </pool>
          </connection>
           <statement>
            <sql>insert into userdetails values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)</sql>
              
            </statement>
        </dbreport>
      </sequence>
Here i want to save simple string like "usman" tell me how can i do it?

Comment: First you need to add the mysql jdbc driver from [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) to ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib. Before proceeding you need to restart the server. Here is a nice blog for the use case  (https://buddhimawijeweera.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/db-report-mediator-in-wso2-esb/)